# How to pass argument to class when object is initiated?

Tags: python, qt, class, scrapy, pyqt5

I'm want to build a gui that has two buttons, "Open Input File" and "Run". When a user clicks on "Open Input File", he/she can select a file from his/her computer that has one column with urls in it. When that person then clicks on "Run", a script based on scrapy is initialised, which uses the urls from the input files as start_urls (example: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html).

My script looks like this:

```
import scrapy
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
file = "Empty"

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    global file
    name = "scriptTest" #name of spider
    allowed_domains = ["web"] #where is spider allowed to crawl
    start_urls = [file] #where will spider crawl

    def parse(self): #scrapes start_urls according to instructions and returns results

class MyGui(object): #gives description of class type MyGui
    filename = 'Empty'
    file = []
    def setupUI(self): #describes how base form of gui will look

    def buttons(self): #creates buttons and connects functions to those buttons
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Input File:")) #creates button with text
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showDialog) #connects button one to function showDialog
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run")) #creates button2 with text
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.runSpider) #connects button two to function runSpider

    def showDialog(self): #opens QFileDialog and sets global file to name of selected file

    def runSpider(self): #should start crawling urls from selected file
        global file
        global filename

        def getUrls(filename): #returns first column containing urls (given by gui user in showDialog) as array.

        file = getUrls() #sets global variable file as returned value of getExcelData
        process = CrawlerProcess() #creates object 'process' that is of type 'Crawlerprocess'
        process.crawl(MySpider) #starts crawling
        process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()

ui = MyGui() #creates object called 'ui' of type 'MyGui
ui.setupUi(window) #launches gui window
```

Like I said, I want to use the urls from the file selected after clicking on pushButton as start_urls for the spider. However, when I click "Run" the spider uses the the value "Empty" as start_urls instead of using the new value of the global variable file. I think I understand why; the class is a description of an object, so when the object is initialised it will have the properties of the described class.

I've tried to fix the problem with something like:

```
class MySpider:
    def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg
```

But I haven't found a solution.

**Q:** How can I pass the file selected by the user to the class MySpider?

Thanks in advance, please correct me if I'm stating something incorrect! (Sorry if my code is really messy/unclear, I'm still learning a lot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_urls = [file]` is not updated when you update `file`. It holds the previous reference of `file`.

A quick workaround (I'm sure a better solution exists) would be to update directly the `start_urls` class variable:

```
MySpider.start_urls = getUrls()
process.crawl(MySpider) #starts crawling
```

The advantage is that you don't need your global `file` variable anymore